# AOSP Build not booting on hammerhead

Tags: android, android-source, nexus-5

So i am new to 'Build android from source'. I recently built a custom ROM (with no changes in AOSP). After syncing the repo, (and downloading hammerhead binaries) I used the following commands:

```
   $. build/envsetup.sh
   $lunch
   $aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
   $export OUT_DIR_COMMON_BASE=/media/entertainment/out
   $make -j4 otapackage
```

It built after taking a significantly long time. The process stopped twice giving ......Error 1. But then I increased the linux-swap space. And everything went OK.

finally, I was able to get the flashable zip in out/target/product/hammerhead/aosp_hammerhead-ota-eng.gaurav-ubuntu.zip (174.7 mb)

I installed this ROM on my nexus 5 using multiROM manager.

**Problem:**

when I boot this ROM, the phone gets stuck on Google Logo, i.e. even the boot screen doesnt show up.

Can anybody guide me, what can be the possible problem ?

Comment: u hv device_owner.xml in ur device?

Comment: I have no idea, what this file is about and where should I find it ?

Comment: u need to flash the device again the google logo stay for 20-25 mins ...wait till that or flash again ur device..i hope u r follwing proper step for the same ...you wanna flash android L? which device u hv?

Comment: My branch is android 4.4.4_r2

Comment: devices? nexus 2013?

Comment: after flash u started recovery mode?

Comment: Nopes. Actually I flashed it using TWRP. And after flashing I began with the ROM.

Comment: connect your device to computer via USB, run Logcat view in your favorite IDE, and checks logs. maybe there is a answer, why your device isn't booting normal.

Comment: There is no target make -j4 otapackage?

Comment: That is not a "target". Thats a make command.  Target is aosp_hammerhead-userdebug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So finally, got the problem. Actually I pulled the android4.4.2_r2 branch and was using google's preview binaries.

Then I pulled the android-4.4.4_r2 branch and used Google Binaries for android 4.4.4_r2. Everything went fine.

Comment: Hello @gaurav414u is this the binary you used? https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/hammerhead-ktu84q-factory-ae475293.tgz

Comment: I dont remember now Ankur.

Comment: No problem Gaurav. Thanks for the reply.  I tried flashing my Nexus 5. But it is getting stuck at the Google Logo. Its more than 10 mins now. I am able to take an adb shell access though. Did you also face this?

Comment: @AnkurBhatia, I downloaded the binaries from here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#hammerheadktu84p
You can match whether these are the same which you are using.

Comment: Thanks @gaurav. I also downloaded the correct ones it seems. Dont know why it is getting stuck at the google Logo. Probably will wait for another 10-15 mins.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed my case by deploying vendor binaries into the android source tree from [google page](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers)

It is quite easy, You download the zip files and run them in the source tree root. They append additional software being embedded int the final img files of the built system.
Rebuild after this takes about 2 mins, because all android build system does is repackage the imgs .

Comment: You could and You probably should clean the output previously generated though. This can be done using

 make clobber